# How to sync values between redis and PostgreSQL table rows?

Tags: postgresql, api, redis, api-gateway

I'm building an API product, where users can use multiple APIs (I give them an API key).

I want to monitor the api calls the user makes to be able to know how many calls they've made (and by extension, how much to charge them).

Here's my table: `user_apis`

```
| API Name | User ID | Total API calls | Successful API calls | Failed API Calls |
|----------|---------|-----------------|----------------------|------------------|
| cat_data | 1       | 15              | 10                   | 5                |
| dog_data | 1       | 3               | 3                    | 0                |
| cat_data | 2       | 1               | 0                    | 0                |
```

A user can use different types of APIs, say `User 1` uses 2 APIs `cat_data` and `dog_data`.

1. Now, when I'm handling the routes that correspond to `cat_data` and `dog_data` APIs, I need to quickly monitor the API call in some kind of middleware.
2. If User 1's API Key hits the endpoint for `cat_data` => Right now I'm counting that hit in redis in a very crude format `key=[user_api_key_total_calls], value=[number_of_calls+1]`, I've built a sort of API gateway middleware through which every request passes through and gets tracked in redis.

I need to use redis (or some in memory store) because these APIs might see very high usage (>100 req/sec), so I cannot make a read + write call to a database on every API endpoint hit.

That brings us to the question: How do I make sure I maintain the integrity of this data in the database?

If I don't write to database every time (say, I choose to write after every 1000 calls) and if the redis instance goes down, then that data is lost! How do I avoid this?

Comment: Did you check Redis Write-Behind solution? https://github.com/RedisGears/rgsync

Comment: Will check it out, thanks! Although, I was hoping for some kind of standard pattern/library that I could follow within my existing API handling code so as to not further complicate my tech stack.

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple solutions for this:

- First of all, You can [persist the Redis data](https://redis.io/topics/persistence) to avoid data-lost. [Redis reliability](https://blog.andyet.com/2012/02/09/redis-reliability-for-realtime-apps/#:%7E:text=Redis%20persistence%20is%20not%20less,%2C%20no%20strange%20corruptions%20possible.%22) is not less than PostgreSQL or any other databases.
- For syncing database and Redis, you can Update all databases rows in one query,  once per 15 seconds(for example). But for making that query you need to know what UserIDs where active sync last update, for this you can save list of active UserIDs in a [Redis set](https://redis.io/topics/data-types).